# gae-sessions with django on gae

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm using gae-sessions with django for writing a gae based app. From here

I've added gaesessions.DjangoSessionMiddleware to settings.py.  A modification is required in

```
self.wrapped_wsgi_middleware = SessionMiddleware(fake_app, cookie_key='you MUST change this')
```

I have put the cookie_key but what is required in place of 'fake_app'. I've main.py where I've  created the application.

```
def main():
    # Create a Django application for WSGI.
    application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

    # Run the WSGI CGI handler with that application.
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Do I need this application instance to pass in place of fake_app?
I'm new to this and do not understand the functionality properly. Please if anyone could explain also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just an anonymous function.

I have taken a look at the [gae-sessions source](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/blob/master/gaesessions/__init__.py#L453), and what I found for `fake-app` is this:

```
[snip]

class DjangoSessionMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self):
        fake_app = lambda environ, start_response : start_response
        self.wrapped_wsgi_middleware = SessionMiddleware(fake_app, cookie_key='you MUST change this')

[snip]
```

Basically the class `DjangoSessionMiddleware` is just a wrapper.

So, this means you don't have to modify `fake_app`, because it's needed for `SessionMiddleware`, but only change change the value of `cookie_key`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create appengine_config.py?

It's pretty straightforward and it is described in:
https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/blob/master/README.markdown

HTH...

Comment: I think with django I don't need to create this file. I've made the necessary changes in settings.py. Also giving a cookie-key it's working. What my concern is about 'fake-app'. What is this?